# An upgrade from 'groovy' to 'impish' is not supported with this tool

Tags: apt, upgrade, sudo, 20.10

This is the error when I type `do-release-upgrade`:

[image]

Error is `An upgrade from 'groovy' to 'impish' is not supported with this tool.`

Make sure that I did

```
sudo-apt-update   
sudo-apt-upgrade  

sudo sed -i "s/old-releases/archive/g" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Comment: There is no direct upgrade from 20.10 to 21.10; you would need to upgrade to 21.04 first, but that interim release is no longer available. If you would like to upgrade to the latest interim release, you will need to make an installation USB and install overtop your current installation 

Comment: You missed your window by a few days.. 20.10 upgraded as already stated by @matigo to *hirsute*, but if you check out https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release you'll note there is a "Supported: 0" or no longer supported because it's EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/).  You can *upgrade via re-install* rather easily with desktop installs; ie. no loss of files, and *manually installed* packages are auto-reinstall (if available in Ubuntu repositories for the new release) but you didn't specify your type of install.

Comment: FYI:  You should `apt full-upgrade` before you attempt *do-release-upgrade* though I suspect it'll make no difference in your case, given the error messages isn't reporting you have updates you've not yet applied (there are cases where `apt upgrade` cannot continue and you need to `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade` to apply upgrades; see `man apt` for more details if needed)   20.04 or the LTS release can go direct (*not generally advised but possible*), but you weren't on the LTS

Comment: The only way to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.10 is by changing `sources.list`. However, that will more likely break your system. As mentioned by Guiverc and Matigo, reinstallation is the best option. Make sure you've a backup of everything important.

Comment: guiverc : I did dist-upgrade and full-upgrade but the same error message had been displayed

Comment: is there a command to reinstall? can i do it without usb?

Comment: You can use whatever devices your hardware will boot from, be it CD, DVD, USB-thumb-drive, SSD, HDD, cflash, even magnetic tape IF your hardware can be made to boot from the media; ie. USB is only one choice.  (FYI: I said I suspected it'd make no difference in your case; as the error message is different if that was your issue; your issue is 21.04 is EOL & you missed the *release-upgrade* window)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I disagree with it being off-topic, as questions about updating to a supported release are on-topic. However, it is a duplicate.

Comment: @guiverc -- how do I do a non-destructive "reinstall?" I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: I'm involved with Lubuntu where it's called *install using existing partition*  (I personally prefer *upgrade via re-install*) where I document it here - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743  (search for "*Install using existing partition:*")   That doc is geared for QA-testers, not end-users & works with all Ubuntu *flavors*... Key is to re-use existing partitions & don't format; the no-format is what triggers this type of install... It's far faster than *release-upgrade* & allows you to skip release during upgrade -- as always backup first

Comment: You'll need to go thru all the intermediate releases until the last one. You should be able to upgrade by downloading the upgrade archives manually, and running them each in turn, following https://butlerraines.com/code-stuff/upgrading-end-life-eol-ubuntu-version-ubuntu-1904 => I'm doing it now, will keep you posted.

Comment: You can follow the directions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/